# How to use a pollevent through out multiple class "Union variable" (sfml)

Tags: c++, sfml

From my understanding how `sf::Event` works there could only be one a loop since they all share the same memory space so my question I would I able to use `sf::Event` throughout my other class with:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

So would I just have reference my `sf::Event` or is this incorrect if I want to share it with my other classes

```
class a{

    void handleEvent(sf::Event& event){
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            {
                std::cout << "the escape key was pressed" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "control:" << event.key.control << std::endl;
                std::cout << "alt:" << event.key.alt << std::endl;
                std::cout << "shift:" << event.key.shift << std::endl;
                std::cout << "system:" << event.key.system << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sf::Event` is implemented as a union of different events' data which means that only one of the data structures is active at the time and it depends on the value of the `type` field, but it's something that works per-instance not per-type.

Hence you can safely pass events around and, if I understood you correctly, your code is fine in this situation.